# Appending output of a for loop for Python to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder with .txt files in it. My code will find the line count and character count in each of these files and save the output for each file in a single csv file in a different directory. The csv file is *Linecount.csv*. For some reason the output to csv file is repeating for character and linecount for the last output, though printing the output is producing correct results. The output of the  print statement is correct.

For the csv file it is not.

```
import glob 
import os 
import csv 

os.chdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload') 

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): 
    chars = lines = 0 
    with open(file,'r')as f: 
        for line in f: 
        lines+=1 
        chars += len(line) 
    a=file 
    b=lines 
    c=chars 
    print(a,b,c) 

    d=open('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Output/LineCount.cs‌​v', 'w') 
    writer = csv.writer(d,lineterminator='\n') 
    for a in os.listdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload'): 
        writer.writerow((a,b,c)) d.close()
```

Comment: import glob
import os
import csv
os.chdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload')
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
 chars = lines = 0
 with open(file,'r')as f:
  for line in f:
   lines+=1
   chars += len(line)
  a=file
  b=lines
  c=chars
  print(a,b,c)

  d=open('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Output/LineCount.csv', 'w')
  writer = csv.writer(d,lineterminator='\n')
  for a in os.listdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload'):
   writer.writerow((a,b,c))
  d.close()

Comment: Please edit the question and include your code there. It is impossible to read as a comment

Comment: Why would you think posting your code in a comment like that is a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Thanks All , I  got it. Sorry for posting the code in comment section. This is my first time here and I was getting a error regarding format while posting which was hard to get rid off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your indentation.

You are looping through each file using `for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):`

This stores the last result in `a`,`b`, and `c`.  It doesn't appear to write it anywhere.

You then loop through each item using `for a in os.listdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload'):`, and store `a` from this loop (the filename), and the last value of `b` and `c` from the initial loop.

I've not run but reordering as follows may solve the issue:

```
import glob 
import os 
import csv 

os.chdir('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Upload') 
d=open('c:/Users/dasa17/Desktop/sample/Output/LineCount.cs‌​v', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(d,lineterminator='\n') 

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): 
        chars = lines = 0 
        with open(file,'r') as f: 
                for line in f: 
                lines+=1 
                chars += len(line) 
        a=file 
        b=lines 
        c=chars 
        print(a,b,c) 
        writer.writerow((a,b,c))
d.close()
```

Comment: Thanks much, I figured that out :)